# What year, make, and model is this car?

Tags: car

I was looking on the internet and wanted to know what type of car this is. Please let me know, thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It's a 2016 Land Rover Defender 110, 2.5L TurboDiesel 6-speed manual operated by ISAK 4x4 Rentals in Iceland (https://www.isak.is/4x4-rental/land-rover-defender/428 - no connection, so this isn't advertising, just a link to vehicle ISAK 34 - the car in this original post is ISAK 30)

Comment: I love the return to historic styling. I thought it was a 1981 Land Rover Defender Series III 109 Stage One V8

Comment: @the_storyteller There's no return unfortunately - the new 'Defender' looks like a generic bland SUV... Pretty much the only difference between the earliest (1983) 110 and the last proper Defender (Jan 2016) was the bulge on the bonnet.